# When does our SE ad update to reflect our full theme?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I don't know if this is intentional or not, but our SE "ad" (below) is still styled in the beta site "sketchy" theme, even though the site has it's full theme.

[image]

Full released sites have ads styled to fit their theme:

[image]

[image]

I was wondering if this was by design or an oversight since our theme *is* done but we're still in beta, I wasn't sure if it's something that's done at the time we're out of beta or if it should be done since our theme is done.

Comment: the change is now live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch. The Ad banner design should've been updated when the new design launched for the main site. I'll update the banner today.